# Laravel Oauth2 Login

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth, laravel-5

I'm adding OAuth2 login to a Laravel 5 site to login using Facebook, Google and Twitter.

By default, the Laravel login has a users table with fields for name, email, password etc.

I want users to be able to sign up and login using their email as standard but also using OAuth2.

I'm just a little confused about how to store the details passed back (eg Name, facebook/google ID). Do I store these in the users table without a password but add an additional field to say whether they've logged in via OAuth?? Or should I create a seperate table for users that signup and login via OAuth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are using for oauth but have a look at :

https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth

Really simple to use - you can use the existing user table, no need to create a separate one.

Hope that helps!

Comment: An option is to use the usual users table for Laravel but to add in another related table for users who have logged in via oauth. That way you can check against that table to see if they had logged in previously. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Hi Mhluzi, I'm using https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel. Based on what you've said I've created a table called social_login. This has a field for social_id (their facebook/google id) and user_id (which references the users table). When they authorise the app they're added to this table and also an entry is created for them in the user table. When they re-sign in using OAuth it can check the social_login table, find their user_id and then authorise then by user_id. Hope this is the right way of doing it! :)